# To which language is Scala most similar from a functional programming perspective?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, ocaml

1. Standard ML
2. OCaml
3. Haskell
4. some other

Comment: "From a functional programming perspective" == "Leaving aside the OO part"? Because othwise, the OO part would rule out SML, Haskell and all other functional languages without OO, leaving (afaik) only OCaml and Common Lisp, in which case the answer must be OCaml.

Comment: Yes, without taking OO part into consideration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is similar in the power of its static type system to Haskell, though its type inferencing is severely hampered by the need to support OO-style subtyping. Scala also [lacks higher-rank polymorphism](http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/07/02/higher-rank-polymorphism-in-scala/) and impredicativity, both of which Haskell has. On the other hand, Scala's implicits-based [type class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class) mechanism, while more verbose than Haskell, is more flexible.

There are many axes on which to compare, of course; Scala's evaluation semantics are [strict](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Strict_evaluation), like that of ML, whereas Haskell is [lazy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation).

Comment: Scala has higher-ranked polymorphism...

Comment: @Kevin Wright: it doesn't have direct support for it. See here: http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/07/02/higher-rank-polymorphism-in-scala/

Comment: You can pass a type constructor as a parameter, that's higher-rank *by definition*.  If by "direct" you mean "with exactly the same syntax as Haskell" then it can be argued that there's a **lot** of stuff not "directly" supported by Scala.

Comment: No, passing a type constructor is not the same as higher-ranked polymorphism, which involves passing a *value* that is generic to a function, such that the function can instantiate it to any type it needs. I think passing a type constructor is called "higher-kind polymorphism".

Comment: @Kevin Wright: You're thinking of higher-kinded types, not higher-rank polymorphism. They're distinct concepts.

Answer (score 3):

Both in feature set and in the way it's being used, Haskell is probably closest from that list, although the actors library shows a strong Erlang heritage.

Something like this: http://dibblego.wordpress.com/2007/05/23/the-power-of-type-classes-with-scala-implicit-defs/  gives a good idea of where Haskell and Scala are equivalent